# How to return a json object in Rails without using render :json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

From what I have read, I can respond to a json request by using the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: t.response }
end
```

My problem is that t.response is already in json format - and I think that my app is breaking because render json: is re-converting it to json. How do I avoid this, and simply return t.response.

Note that if I simply have t.response as my last line in the controller, the corresponding view is rendered - which is obviously not json.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am trying to get this working so I can send sms via tropo. If you have used tropo before, do you have any suggestions how to respond back to tropo correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show you how Rails deals with converting to json format. It's basically on line:

```
json = json.to_json(options) unless json.kind_of?(String)
```

So, strings aren't converted, other objects are converted to String via their `to_json` method. If your `t.response` returns a string then no conversion is performed.

Answer (score 5):

`render json:` just sets the content type to application/json (and calls `to_json` on the object passed to it if the object responds to `to_json`). It doesn't convert or somehow modifies your response.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

Comment: *if the object responds to to_json*. It's funny, but ALL objects in Rails respond to `to_json`, so there's no need to perform checking. Even `42.to_json` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can render text instead

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render text: t.response }
end
```